# Back and forward in IFrame from browser

Tags: iframe, back, forward

I have an iframe which loads search results. I need people when push back/forward buttons on browser to work on iframe. Right now if you push the buttons it gives some error in iframe ''This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displaye,etc.."
and looks pretty nasty. Maybe someone have something better in mind to fix this problem. I need only when iframe load results to enable this function.